# lstm for time series analysis keras showing numpy.ndarray object has no attribute '_validate_or_infer_batch_size'

Tags: keras, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to build an lstm model that takes in time series data and output some predictions. I tried running below code and i got numpy.ndarray object has no attribute '_validate_or_infer_batch_size'. Please help thanks. Do tell me if any other information is required.

```
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, time_step, x_t.shape[2]), dropout=0.0, 
recurrent_dropout=0.0, stateful=True,     kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
lstm_model.add(Dense(20,activation='relu'))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01)
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)


csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log', append=True)

history = Model.fit(x_t, y_t, epochs=epochs, verbose=2, batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=False, validation_data=(trim_dataset(x_val, batch_size),
                    trim_dataset(y_val, batch_size)), callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some issue in your batch size variable. What is your batch size?

Comment: the batch size i declared as 30

Comment: And how does x_t & y_t look like?